# JSP web design tool

Tags: jsp

I was wondering what do you guys use to design the .jsp file? I know it needs to be coded, but is there an easy way to build the layout in jsp? Tables..etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every modern IDE for Java has some plugin that will give you code completion to make a jsp.
Only thing that you need to now is what you are trying to represent on a page and that final product will be basic html.
So 2. options: 
1. give some designer to make you all the pages you need , and then change them according to your specification or 
2. Try this: Photoshop + slicing + html design (html + css - some grid system perheps) + add jsp tags :-)

Answer (score 3):

A graphic artist, or someone who knows how to do proper design, creates an HTML layout with flexible CSS rules.

Then, you change `.html` to `.jsp` and have at it.